# SQL - Return most recent batch of sequential rows

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014

Version:
Microsoft SQL Server 2014 (SP3-CU4) (KB4500181)

What i'm trying to accomplish here is pull in all the rows where there is a break of less than lets say 40 days between the next row.

So in the first example there is an uninterrupted break every month (roughly). So I would like the query to pull in all records here.

Example 1

```
CREATE table #Temp1
(
id Varchar(50),
DT8 int,
series int
) 

INSERT INTO #Temp1
VALUES
('147501',20181022,1),
('147502',20181115,1),
('147503',20181211,1),
('147504',20190110,1),
('147506',20190306,1),
('147505',20190205,1),
('147507',20190402,1),
('147508',20190429,1),
('147509',20190529,1),
('147510',20190603,1),
('147511',20190703,1),
('147512',20190802,1),
('177901',20190905,1),
('177902',20191001,1),
('177903',20191108,1),
('177904',20191205,1),
('190401',20200103,1),
('190402',20200205,1)
```

In example two there is a gap greater than 40 days between Sep 25 2019 and January 29 2020.  So I would like the query to just pull in the most recent subsequent block.  In this case it would just be the top record.

Example 2

```
INSERT INTO #Temp1
VALUES
('164701',20190605,2),
('164702',20190703,2),
('164703',20190802,2),
('164704',20190904,2),
('164705',20190925,2),
('189101',20200129,2)
```

I have started down this road, and was looking at using LEAD to calculate the number of days between the current and previous rows.  I realize I probably need to break the years out to account for the case when moving to a new year or convert it to a real date so that I can use some sql functions to calculate the difference in days for me.

After that I wasn't sure how to go about only returning the most recent consecutive block.  Thought I would ask here to see if anyone had any insight on how to accomplish this.

Comment: Using window functions is a good approach. Another method is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55348963/getting-the-missing-ids-from-a-table-by-storing-the-records-into-an-array-and-co/55349674#55349674). What do you want the output to look like?

Comment: Please, please, **always** include your version of MySQL - it's **very** important as they've introduced many important features recently! Also, in future, could you provide your tables as DDL (`CREATE TABLE...`) in **formatted** text and your data in the form of DML (`INSERT INTO...`) - it makes life much easier for those of us trying to help. p.s. welcome to the forum! :-)

Comment: @danblack, I am mainly concerned with the number of rows returned.  Because I want to COUNT() the number of consecutive entries for the most recent block.

Comment: @Vérace good point on the MySQL version, and thank you for the tip!

Comment: Why would `Date` an `INT`??? So you can enter 20201335?

Comment: @Eric, yeah It's just the way dates are stored in this particular table i'm referencing.  (old system) Not sure all the reasons for the original implementation.

Comment: Previously you tag `MySQL`.  It's not the case anymore?  So are you using MySQL or SQL Server?

Comment: @Eric my inexperience is showing, I guess the database is a SQL Server...  I thought MySQL and SQL Server were ambiguous.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```sql
WITH 
cte1 AS 
(
SELECT series, 
       id, 
       `date`, 
       DATEDIFF(LEAD(STR_TO_DATE(`date`, '%Y%m%d')) OVER (PARTITION BY series
                                                          ORDER BY `date`),
                STR_TO_DATE(`date`, '%Y%m%d')) diff
FROM test
),
cte2 AS 
(
SELECT series, 
       id, 
       `date`, 
       COALESCE(SUM(diff > 40) OVER (PARTITION BY series
                                     ORDER BY `date` DESC), 0) grp
FROM cte1
)
SELECT series, 
       id, 
       `date` 
FROM cte2 
WHERE grp = 0
ORDER BY 1,3
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=bc846ece42e1309cd1e24111f2b61b75)

Comment: Thank you Akina, I can see that you have solved it!  I don't have access to the STR_TO_DATE function i'm guessing due to my MySQL version.  But this should do it for me.  Appreciate it.

Comment: `my MySQL version`...? But you've edited your question to show that your server is `Version: Microsoft SQL Server 2014`. I even edited the tags for the question (also very important for those searching...).